# What types to choose on my input form?

Tags: php, html, input, types

I'm trying to make a page where users can add songs to my database. I have some problems with it. When I try it out, the ID, Album Titel and Artiest are added to my database properly, but I only get no value for Duur and 0.00 for Prijs, which is not wat I tried to add.

My code is below:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="int(5)" name="ID"> ID <br>
<input type="text" name="Titel">Titel<br>
<input type="text" name="Artiest">Artiest<br>
<input type="varchar(6)" name"Duur">Duur<br>
<input type="decimal(5,2)" name"Prijs">Prijs<br>

<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php

$inputid = $_POST['ID'];
$users_name = $_POST['Titel'];
  $users_email = $_POST['Artiest'];
  $users_website = $_POST['Duur'];
  $users_comment = $_POST['Prijs'];





  $query = "
  INSERT INTO `Album`(`ID`, `Album Titel`, `Artiest`, `Duur`, `Prijs`) VALUES ('$inputid', '$users_name',
        '$users_email', '$users_website', '$users_comment');";

  $result = $conn->query($query);;


  echo "<h2>Thank you for your Comment!</h2>";

  mysql_close($con);

?>
```

The database is linked properly, so that is not the problem. 
I have the exact same input types a I have in my database structure.

Can somebody help me out?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: varchar and decimal and int are not input types these are database tables coloum type

Comment: @Vicky Okay thanks, do you know where I should change them to in the html form?

Comment: Use <input type="number" instead <input type="int(5)"

Comment: You should avoid learning or writing new code using PHP's `mysql_*` functions. They have been removed in the latest version and your code won't work in the future. Please read [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for information on why and what to replace them with.

Answer (score 1):

List of all available input types: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

```
   <form method="post">

    <!-- Add required attribute if you don't want user to leave it blank  -->

    ID: <input type="text" name="id" required /> <br>
    Title: <input type="text" name="title" required /><br>
    Artist<input type="text" name="artist" required /><br>

    <!-- allow user to enter float values between your choice -->
    Duration: <input type="number" min="0" max="10" step="0.01" name="duration" required /><br>


    Price: <input type="number" min="0" max="999.00" step="0.01" required name="price" /><br>

    <input type="submit">
</form>


    <?php

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $artist = $_POST['artist'];
    $duration = $_POST['duration'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO `Album`(`ID`, `Album Titel`, `Artiest`, `Duur`, `Prijs`) VALUES ('$id', '$title',
            '$artist', '$duration', '$price');";

      $result = $conn->query($query);;


      echo "<h2>Thank you for your Comment!</h2>";

      mysql_close($con);
```

**Update**: You forgot to put '**=**' sign in names of last two input fields, thats why they were not getting POSTED.

I have edited my original answer.

Here's a edited version of you code i have tried :

```
<form method="post">

        <!-- Add required attribute if you don't want user to leave it blank  -->

        ID: <input type="text" name="id" required /> <br>
        Title: <input type="text" name="title" required /><br>
        Artist<input type="text" name="artist" required /><br>

        <!-- allow user to enter max 6 characters -->
        Duration: <input type="number" min="0" max="10" step="0.01" name="duration" required /><br>

        <!-- allow user to enter float values between your choice -->
        Price: <input type="number" min="0" max="999.00" step="0.01" required name="price" /><br>

        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <?php
      print_r( $_POST );


    ?>
```

Which gives me this output [image]

If you are new to programming, then **please use some appropriate variable names so that others can understand your code better**.

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your help. I feel like it is close. But unfortunately I still get the same problem. There is no value for Duur and the value is always 0.00 voor Prijs, whatever I enter. To clarify it a little. Duur means duration, so I want the length of an album in there with for example 33:45 which means 33 minutes and 45 seconds. Prijs means price and I want a decimal value over there with 2 decimals, for example 7.99

Answer (score 0):

HTML has only following input types http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_form_input_types.asp. You have to maintain strict data types only in database not in HTML. For HTML use one of the above enlisted input types.

```
<input type="number" name="ID"> ID <br>
<input type="text" name="Titel">Titel<br>
<input type="text" name="Artiest">Artiest<br>
<input type="number" name"Duur">Duur<br>
<input type="number" name"Prijs">Prijs<br>
```

Comment: text is not supported in number he wants varchar  **name"Duur"** and it should be  name="Duur"